# Cannot apt remove/purge, but showing in "apt list"

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, software-center

Using the command "apt list | grep audacity", below packages are listed,

```
audacity-data/focal,focal 2.3.3-1build1 all
audacity/focal 2.3.3-1build1 amd64
```

But when I try to remove the above packages by "sudo apt remove audacity/focal", I can't.

getting below,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'audacity' is not installed, so not removed
Selected version '2.3.3-1build1' (Ubuntu:20.04/focal [amd64]) for 'audacity'
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

I need to uninstall audacity from apt since I have already installed the same using flatpak. Any idea how to remove above. There are two audacity listed in my pc.

I tried to uninstall it from the ubuntu software center as well, but it's not loading the audacity.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your output of `apt list | grep audacity` is as follows:

```
audacity-data/focal,focal 2.3.3-1build1 all
audacity/focal 2.3.3-1build1 amd64
```

The above results show that the audacity apt package is not installed. If the audacity apt package was installed the results of `apt list | grep audacity` would be as follows:

```
audacity-data/focal,focal 2.3.3-1build1 all [installed,automatic]
audacity/focal 2.3.3-1build1 amd64 [installed]
```

`[installed]` in the above results is shown in bold text. If audacity was installed the command to remove audacity and audacity-data would be `sudo apt remove audacity audacity-data`

Comment: I tried "sudo apt remove audacity audacity-data", still I am getting, Package 'audacity' is not installed, so not removed. Package 'audacity-data' is not installed, so not removed

Comment: @IsuruDewasurendra In the third paragraph of my answer it says "The above results show that the audacity apt package is not installed." as you mentioned in the preceding comment, so in a direct way there's my answer to your question.